# Leaflet custom marker

Tags: javascript, leaflet, marker

I want to create a custom marker but more complex than just changing the icon. I want to create something like group of markers based on given number of slots. So, for example - for 5 slots it should look like this:
[image]
and every of these 5 slots in the group should be independent for actions - on mouse over (show some tooltip), click (open some modal), etc. But the dragging should work for whole group. I suppose I should create new class based on L.Marker or L.Layer. Could you help me where to start? And is it even possible?

Comment: So something like https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Marker.Stack , then?

Comment: Is it possible to create a running sample where we can reproduce the same issue.. Add here whatever you have tried so far... .jsfiddle or stackoverflow editor?